# How can I set secret global variables in Rails and put the file in .gitignore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, gitignore

I have a rails app that connects to various APIs, and instead of putting my API keys directly in the Rails project, I'd like to make a separate file, secrets.rb, that contains global string variables for all of my API secret keys.

Where should I save this, and how can I make sure that these globals will be included where I need them in my project?

Comment: I use environment variables for most of my API connections. In development I put them in the `config/environments/development.rb` file and add this file to gitignore. In production I make them environment variables on the server it's self. Granted I usually deploy to heroku which makes this very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an initializer with your API constants and add it to `.gitignore`:

```
# config/initializers/secrets.rb

API_KEY = 'my_api_key'
API_SECRET_KEY = 'my_api_secret_key'
```

You could add them to `config/environments/development.rb` as suggested by @engineersmnky in the comments, but you typically *want* to add `development.rb` into version control.

Comment: [engineersmnky suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038371/how-can-i-set-secret-global-variables-in-rails-and-put-the-file-in-gitignore#comment38942229_25038371) to use environment variables

Answer (score 0):

I think better way is a create config.yml and add to gitignore.

```
# config/config.yml

development:
 api_key = 'dev_key'

test:
 api_key = 'test_key'

# config/initializers/app_config.rb

AppConfig = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'config.yml'))[Rails.env]
```